# Use variable as RegEx pattern

Tags: regex, perl, variables

I'd like to use a variable as a RegEx pattern for matching filenames:

```
my $file = "test~";
my $regex1 = '^.+\Q~\E$';
my $regex2 = '^.+\\Q~\\E$';
print int($file =~ m/$regex1/)."\n";
print int($file =~ m/$regex2/)."\n";
print int($file =~ m/^.+\Q~\E$/)."\n";
```

The result (or on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/x2TbFm)):

```
0
0
1
```

Can anyone explain to me how I can use a variable as a RegEx pattern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use `\Q` in a single-quoted / non-interpolated string.  It must be seen by the lexer.

Anyway, tilde isn’t a meta-character.

Add `use regex "debug"` and you will see what is actually happening.

Comment: Thanks, I use `$regex =~ s/\\Q(.*?)\\E/quotemeta($1)/ge;` to replace \Q..\E. Is there any other way?

Comment: @user72757 Yes, don't put `\Q` `\E` in your strings in the first place.

Comment: strange, it was asked about RegEx as a variable, but it seems the discussion  moved to `\Q` and `\E` :/

Comment: use regex "debug" gave an error. I found that use re "debug" worked.

Answer (score 89):

As [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) says:

```
    $re = qr/$pattern/;
    $string =~ /foo${re}bar/; # can be interpolated in other patterns
    $string =~ $re; # or used standalone
    $string =~ /$re/; # or this way
```

So, use the `qr` quote-like operator.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm a give you a bounty of 150 points

Comment: @GlassGhost - Did you open the bounty before you read this or after? Do you have to wait until it expires to give the points? Anyway, `qr//` creates a regex object, but you have to be careful what you feed it. If its a literal you must run a quotemeta() on it first.

Comment: @sln you have to wait 24 hours in order to spend a bounty.

Comment: @sln I'm having trouble getting recursive regexes working on line 22 of: https://github.com/Viruliant/Tromp/blob/master/Bruijn.pl#L22

Comment: @GlassGhost - To be clear, `$RecursiveRegex` is a variable name and does not represent a recursive regular expression. I looked at your github code. I'm not sure what you are doing so I'll just address the error you're getting. You're using an _eval_ modifier on the substitution form `s///e`. The substitution side will be executed as code with the result being returned to the caller, the regex engine. For _code_ anything wrapped in paren's is isolated from operators.

Comment: @GlassGhost - _(con't)_ So, you have `\(${var}\)`. And with code, it is parsed with priority. `\ ` is an operator trying to take a reference to something. `(` is an operator trying to find it's closing parenthesis `)`, but before it finds it, it see's `\ ` a reference operator to something. It sees that `)` is not proper syntax of a valid reference operator sequence, so it stops before using the closing parenthesis with an `Expected operator before the backslash`. You get this message because the paren's operator construct is the current one being parsed. _Hope this might help!_

Comment: @GlassGhost - Finally, if you use `$str =~ s/\(a${RecursiveRegex}/"(". $RecursiveRegexSubst . ")"/gsme;` that will result in wrapping your regex string in parenthesis literals. It's equivalent to `$repl = "(". $RecursiveRegexSubst . ")"; $str =~ s/\(a${RecursiveRegex}/$repl/gsm;`