# perl use variable under a pattern regex

Tags: regex, perl

How to use variable in the pattern ?

Please I want to this :

```
my $project="SDK" //or something that i will get it after calling some function.
my $JIRA_regex = '(^| )($project)-(\d+)';
print "pattern = $JIRA_regex\n";
```

Output is not good :

```
(^| )($project)-(\d+)
```

---

Thank you :)

1 - Yes I want to use $project, as string value to match or a regex too:

2 - $JIRA_regex will be matched further on the code.

This is my code that it works fine now :

```
my $repo=$ARGV[0];
my $comment=$ARGV[1];

my $project_pattern="[A-Z]{2,5}";

if ($repo =~ "test1.git" or $repo =~ "test2.git")
{
    $project_pattern = "\QSDK\E";
}

my $JIRA_regex = "(^| )($project_pattern)-(\\d+)";

if ( $comment =~ /$JIRA_regex/m )
{
    print "matched $2-$3\n";
}
else
{
    print "not matched\n";
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041877/use-variable-as-regex-pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes don't interpolate variables; double quotes do.

```
my $project = "SDK"; # or whatever
my $JIRA_regex = "(^| )($project)-(\\d+)";
print "pattern = $JIRA_regex\n";
```

(Note that I had to escape the backslash to get a literal `\d` into the string.)

There are some other things to consider:

- Is `$project` supposed to be interpreted as a regex? (Probably not, in which case it should be wrapped in `\Q` `\E` or `quotemeta()`.)
- Does `$JIRA_regex` have to be a plain string? If not, it's easier to make it a regex object.

In which case a better solution would be:

```
my $project = "SDK"; # or whatever
my $JIRA_regex = qr/(^| )(\Q$project\E)-(\d+)/;
print "pattern = $JIRA_regex\n";
```